# Help me with this plot

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I need to plot this function $$ \Omega_{rq}=\sqrt{1+\frac{1-\epsilon_{dd}\left[\frac{2-5\kappa^2}{2(1-\kappa^2)}+\frac{\kappa^2(6+9\kappa^2)f_s(\kappa)}{4(1-\kappa^2)^2}\right]}{1+\epsilon_{dd}\left[\frac{3}{2}\frac{\kappa^2 f_s(\kappa)}{1-\kappa^2}-1\right]}}$$
as a function of $\lambda$ for $\epsilon_{dd}=0.42$. The values of kappa and lambda are the values that solve the equation. 
$$3\kappa^2 \epsilon_{dd}\left[\left(\frac{\lambda^2}{2}+1\right)\frac{f_s(\kappa)}{1-\kappa^2}-1\right]+(\epsilon_{dd}-1)(\kappa^2-\lambda^2)=0 $$ where $$f_s(\kappa)=\frac{1+2\kappa^2}{1-\kappa^2}-\frac{3\kappa^2 artanh \sqrt{1-\kappa^2} }{(1-\kappa^2)^{3/2}}. $$

My code:

```
edd=0.42

Do[Print[FindRoot[ 3 y^2 edd ((i^2/2 + 1) *(((1 + 2 y^2)/(1 - y^2)) - (3 y^2 ArcTanh[Sqrt[1 - y^2]])/(1 - y^2)^(3/2))/(1 - y^2) -1) + (edd - 1) (y^2 - i^2), {y, 0.1}]], {i, 0.2, 5, 0.1}]

Data = Import["C:\\Users\\Desktop\\dd\\teste.txt", "Data"]

Do[Print[Sqrt[   1 + (1 - 
   edd ((2 - 
        5 Data[[j]]^2)/(2 (2 - Data[[j]]^2))) + (Data[[j]]^2 (6 + 
         9 Data[[
            j]]^2) (((1 + 2 Data[[j]]^2)/(1 - 
             Data[[j]]^2)) - (3 Data[[j]]^2 ArcTanh[
             Sqrt[1 - Data[[j]]^2]])/(1 - Data[[j]]^2)^(3/2)))/
     4*(1 - Data[[j]]^2)^2)/(1 + 
   edd (3/2 (((((1 + 2 Data[[j]]^2)/(1 - 
                Data[[j]]^2)) - (3 Data[[j]]^2 ArcTanh[
                Sqrt[1 - Data[[j]]^2]])/(1 - Data[[j]]^2)^(3/
                2)) Data[[j]]^2)/(1 - Data[[j]]^2)) - 1))]], {j,   1, 8, 1}]
```

Is this code correct?

Comment: You ask if your code is correct. Correct for what? It certainly isn't going to give you an expression or a function you can plot. It won't even give you values of Ω from which you could make a list plot. Further, if is not clear how the data you import fits in. We will likely need to see that data to help you. Finally, using `Do` and `Print` is probably wrong; you should look at `Table`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand your code, but you shouldn't use names starting with upper case letters, because these are meant for built-in functions.

To plot `Ω` as a function of `λ`, your functions must be defined:

```
ϵ = 0.42;
fs[κ_] = (1 + 2 κ^2)/(1 - κ^2) - 3 κ^2 ArcTanh[Sqrt[1 - κ^2]] (1 - κ^2)^(-3/2);
eq[λ_, κ_] = 3 κ^2 ϵ ((λ^2/2 + 1) fs[κ]/(1 - κ^2) - 1) + (ϵ - 1) (κ^2 - λ^2);
Ω[λ_, κ_] = Sqrt[1 + (1 - ϵ ((2 - 5 κ^2)/(2 (1 - κ^2)) + (κ^2 (6 + 9 κ^2) fs[κ])/(4 (1 - κ^2)^2)))/(1 + ϵ (3/2 κ^2 fs[κ]/(1 - κ^2) - 1))];
```

The equation can be solved w.r.t. `λ` (I select just the positive solution which is all we need because the function to plot is even)

```
λsol[κ_] = λ /. Last[Solve[eq[λ, κ] == 0, λ]];
```

Now the plot can be parametrized by `κ`

```
ParametricPlot[{λsol[κ], Ω[λsol[κ], κ]}, {κ, 0, 8}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

To show the evenness plot instead `{{-λsol[κ], Ω[λsol[κ], κ]}, {λsol[κ], Ω[λsol[κ], κ]}}`